# What's the best way to upgrade an old 1.2 meteor project to latest version 1.6 ?

Tags: node.js, meteor, architecture, upgrade, meteor-blaze

I have a big 1.2 meteor project which I want to upgrade to latest version of meteor 1.6.

I have two paths to choose from and I am not sure which one to take, I need to know which criteria to consider when making my decision:

1- Try to upgrade website this way: 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 1.4 -> 1.5 -> 1.6 following guidelines mentioned here: https://guide.meteor.com/1.6-migration.html

2- Setup a fresh meteor 1.6 installation, then develop all site functionalities step by step. using reusable code, upgrading good packages, replace no longer maintained packages with more reliable meteor or npm packages.

A meteor expert opinion is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going step by step is going to hurt. I would just jump to 1.6 and see what is broken first. Things may still work as they are.

The biggest problem you will face is the new `imports` folder that you won't have without doing it manually.

It depends how big your code base is, and what packages you are using. I would be tempted to start again, some code might survive the jump, but it's a good opportunity to refactor the code and make the app better anyway.